# Is there any way to prevent/protect a method from breaking during a configuration change?

Tags: android, android-activity

Say:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  ...

  public void doingSomething() {
  ...
  ...
  //the configuration change occurs here
  ...
  ...
  }

...

}
```

I need to protect the method above from breaking due to a configuration change.

Comment: If your method is called on the main (UI) thread, a configuration change cannot interrupt it. Why do you think this is happening? Please provide more details.

Comment: @DavidWasser Are you sure?

Comment: When a configuration change occurs, it is delivered to your `Activity` by a call to `onConfigurationChanged()` (if you have told Android that you want to handle the configuration change yourself) or by a calls to `onPause(), onStop()` and `onDestroy()` in the default case where Android kills the `Activity` and recreates it. In all of these cases, the calls are made on the main (UI) thread. If you have a method running on the main (UI) thread, then these calls cannot be made until your method completes. What are you seeing?

Comment: @DavidWasser Well i have a countdowntimer, inside the on finish() method i have some code (updating variables values, updating views visibility). And sometimes the variables and the views doesn't update when i rotate the phone just in the exact time that my countdowntimer reaches zero (trying to find bugs rotating phone in that exact time). Thats why i thougth the configuration change was breaking my onfinish() method. Edit: I'm using onSavedInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState to restore my activity state.

Comment: Well, all these methods are called on the main (UI) thread. So they cannot interrupt each other.

Comment: But you could handle the orientation change yourself, which would prevent your `Activity` from being destroyed and recreated, which might give you better control of this. Add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your `<activity>` declaration in the manifest and handle the changes in `onConfigurationChanged()`.

Comment: Is so easy to handle that then, I just need to set a flag inside the `onFinish()`. My biggest concern was: if the method breaks in the middle of the execution and I execute the `onFinish()` again, I could increase a variable that was already increased.

Comment: Added an answer. You can accept this answer (or create one of your own and accept that), which will get this question off the unanswered questions list and may also help others who have similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a configuration change occurs, it is delivered to your `Activity` by a call to `onConfigurationChanged()` (if you have told Android that you want to handle the configuration change yourself) or by a calls to `onPause(), onStop()` and `onDestroy()` in the default case where Android kills the `Activity` and recreates it. In all of these cases, the calls are made on the main (UI) thread. If you have a method running on the main (UI) thread, then these calls cannot be made until your method completes.